# Multiple DataContext requiring an Extension Method

Tags: c#

I've got multiple data context, they require the same extension method.  What would be the ideal way in this class, to make it more generic for the return type?

```
public static class DBContextExtensions
{
     public static TContext Attach<TEntity, TContext>(this TContext context, TEntity entity) where TEntity : class, IEntity
     {
          context.Entry(entity).State = entity.Id == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
          return context;
     }
}
```

It doesn't appear to resolve the `Entry` method in Entity Framework.  How could I expose the method via a generic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greg,

Add another generic constraint:

```
public static TContext Attach<TEntity, TContext>(this TContext context, TEntity entity) 
    where TEntity : class, IEntity 
    where TContext : DbContext      //  <----- add this constraint
```

Comment: Without that additional constraint, `TContext` is just an `object`.